# How to select parent by most recent child with Activerecord

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a `user` model which `has many` subscriptions. I need to make two selections:

1. `active users` defined as user with a subscription in the last month
2. `inactive users` the ones that don't meet the (1) criteria

My `subscription` model has a simple scope `.latest` which is defined as `ordered("created_at DESC").first`.

To make selection (1) I use:

```
User.joins(:subscriptions).where("subscriptions.created_at > ?", 1.month.ago).distinct
```

This works, no problem there. However, I can't seem to define a working query for selection (2). Currently I use selection (1) and 'subtract' that from `User.all` to get the remaining users. This feels a bit like a hack.

The selection I need is:

`all users whose most recent subscription was created more than 1 month ago`

It's the `most recent` part of the query that has me stuck.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Quick & dirty way: use complex SQL like this**

Assume you are using auto incremental ID

```
User.select("users.*, MAX(subscriptions.id) as last_subscription_id")
    .joins(:subscriptions)
    .group("subscriptions.user_id")
    .having("last_subscription_id = (select id from subscriptions where user_id=users.id and created_at < '2017-10-01 09:23:28.182475' order by id desc limit 1)")
```

**Recommended way**

Add `last_subscription_id` to `users` table and setup a `belongs_to` relationship `user belongs_to last_subscription` then do the `joins` normally. You need to update `last_subscription_id` of an user when new subscription for this user is created too.

Example: `User` class looks like this (I include `has_many :subscriptions` to show that we have 2 relations now)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subscriptions
  belongs_to :last_subscription, class_name: 'Subscription', foreign_key: :last_subscription_id
end
```

And query will be

```
User.joins(:last_subscription).where("subscriptions.created_at < ?", 1.month.ago)
```

Comment: I like the second approach, just coded it in - but still have trouble formulating the query: `User.joins(:subscriptions).where("last_subscription.created_at < ?", date)` doesn't work..could you give an example?

Comment: I have just updated the answer to include the example. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

for the most recent part you can do this.

```
User.joins("LEFT JOIN subscriptions ON subscriptions.user_id = users.id").order("subscriptions.created_at DESC").select("subscriptions.created_at AS max_date").group_by(&:id).select{|key, value| value[0].max_date < 1.month.ago}.values.flatten
```